# How to increment by group

Tags: java-8

There is a table and now add a new column -- `sort_num int default 0`

```
id  level   sort_num
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   2   0
4   2   0
5   2   0
6   3   0
7   3   0
8   3   0
9   3   0
```

Now I want to set sort_num values like below

```
id  level   sort_num
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   2   1
4   2   2
5   2   3
6   3   1
7   3   2
8   3   3
9   3   4
```

The Java code implement above requirement is

```
    int sortNum = 0;
    int currentLevel = fooList.get(0).getLevel();
    for (RuleConf foo : fooList) {
        if(currentLevel != foo.getLevel()){
            sortNum = 0;
            currentLevel = foo.getLevel();
        }
        foo.setSortNum(++sortNum);
    }
```

I want to know if `Java8` could simplify above code？

PS. Use `mysql` to implement this requirement

```
set @index:=0; update t set sort_num = (@index:=@index+1) where level = 1 order by id;
set @index:=0; update t set sort_num = (@index:=@index+1) where level = 2 order by id;
set @index:=0; update t set sort_num = (@index:=@index+1) where level = 3 order by id;
```

Comment: If you mean `Stream` instead of `Java 8`, then I would say no. Because there are states which depend on already seen elements.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to stick to your plain enhanced for loop. I don't think it is possible to come up with a single `Stream` solution, since you need to have intermediate values. Like:

```
Map<Integer, List<RuleConf>> levels = fooList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RuleConf::getLevel));
levels.values().forEach(v -> 
    IntStream.range(0, v.size()).forEach(i -> v.get(i).setSortNum(i + 1))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the next order numbers yourself, you may do it with one stream. This solution is thread safe as well, hence should work with parallel streams:

```
Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> orders = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
fooList.stream().forEachOrdered(foo -> {
    orders.putIfAbsent(foo.getLevel(), new AtomicInteger());
    foo.setOrder(orders.get(foo.getLevel()).incrementAndGet());
});
```

It should outperform the other stream-solutions, because it requires to iterate over the list only ones.

Comment: @Flown: I do not see why the solution I provided does rely on any order? Is it important / a requirement that the `id` should be taken into account as well?

Comment: Hence I should change the `forEach` into `forEachOrdered` which corrects the solution but sacrifices performance (which was never requested).